# Assign value to input, takes two posts

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

On `<li>` click I set the value to a hidden input like this

```
$(".total").click(function () {
    $("input[name=hid4]").val("4");
});
```

on click on my `<li>` it also posts my form with ajax to a page where it gets all data and returns it.

However, on that page i request the value I just set on click, `var getVal = request.form["hid4"];`, and then for testing I just wrote it out like this `<a>@getVal</a>` and it takes 2 posts before it updates, why is that? how can I have it be updated after first post?

Ajax code:

```
function mySubmit(theForm) {
    theForm = $(theForm).closest("form");
    $.ajax({ // create an AJAX call...
        data: $(theForm).serialize(), // get the form data
        type: $(theForm).attr('method'), // GET or POST
        url: $(theForm).attr('action'), // the file to call
        success: function (response) { // on success..
            $('#here').html(response); // update the DIV
        }
    });
}
```

list in form

```
<div class="holdLiftMenu">
    <ul class="holdLiftMenuUL">
        <li class="holdLiftMenuLI">
            <a onclick="mySubmit(this)" class="holdLiftMenuA total current">Total
                <input type="hidden" name="hid4" id="hid4" value="" />
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Why not put the `$.ajax` call right after the `val('4')` in the unobtrusive event handler? This way you can remove the outdated `on*` event attributes too.

Comment: Just add the line where you are assigning value to the hidden field to the submit function.

Comment: on click you will fire two event.
why not use only one onclick ?

Comment: well, I actually have four "tabs" in my li, I just didnt include them all so it would be easier to read! @Dherya

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can choose from this solutions

Sol 1- remove  onclick="mySubmit(this)" and change

```
$(".total").click(function () {
   $("input[name=hid4]").val("4");
   mySubmit($(this))
  });
```

Sol 2- remove $(".total").click(function () and add $("input[name=hid4]").val("4"); in function mySubmit(theForm)

```
function mySubmit(theForm) {
 $("input[name=hid4]").val("4");
theForm = $(theForm).closest("form");
$.ajax({ // create an AJAX call...
    data: $(theForm).serialize(), // get the form data
    type: $(theForm).attr('method'), // GET or POST
    url: $(theForm).attr('action'), // the file to call
    success: function (response) { // on success..
        $('#here').html(response); // update the DIV
    }
   });
}
```